# TypeScript Typings - Export submodule sub namespace

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Lets say I have a module that export part of a submodule.
For example I'm exporting submodule.namespace.

How do I do that in my .d.ts?

**Edit**: More information

Let's say my module only line of code is 
`module.exports = require('submodule').stuff;`

How do I define my typings?

Comment: Do you have any code you could post? The description alone doesn't not make much sense to me at least.

Comment: Faire enough :) I've included a minimal example.